# Um único ArrayObject para apresentação e alteração

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-5

Olá, estou me aventurando em Angular 8, e me deparei com um impasse, eu obtenho o seguinte obj array de um serviço:

```
this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (products: Product[]) => {
         this.productsToShow = products;
         this.productsToEdit = products;
         // ja tentei fazer = [...products], etc
      });
```

e sempre que eu edito o formulário do objeto `productsToEdit`, automaticamente a grid de exibição é modificada, na grid existe um `ngfor` e sendo exibido da maneira convencional `{{ element.atributo }}`, existe algum jeito de "congelar" a exibição?

Comment: Não ficou nada clara sua pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece ser que vc ta esta copiando a mesma referencia, tenta assim:

```
this.productsToShow = {...products};
this.productsToEdit =Object.assign({}, products);
```

Ou pra ter totalmente outro objeto:

```
 this.productsToShow =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
```

Comment: era exatamente isso, estava pesquisando como o javascript funciona, e aprendo cada dia mais com ela, obrigado